# Parsing a String to add elements within

Tags: java, string, twitter

So what I have is a string which contains a tweet, let us call it `tweetString`. Now my goal is to display this string in terminal but I want to change the color of the hashtags which I can do using `ANSI_YELLOW` and `ANSI_RESET` before and after the hashtag.

So for example, if my string was: `"Hello world #computerScience"`

I could modify it like so to get the hashtag to be colored in as yellow: `"Hello world ANSI_YELLOW #computerScience ANSI_RESET"`

The issue really comes down to how can I do this? For now I want to ignore the fact that the tweet may contain a `#` symbol within their tweet that isn't a hashtag.

Does anyone know of a way I can parse the string and insert the variable calls?

Comment: so if there is not hashtag you won't color it right?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo preferably but I can try to filter that later, so long as I am able to find a `#` and insert the variables, I will be happy with at the moment

Comment: @RC. I tried breaking the string down into characters and searching through each one to see if there is a "#" which isn't too difficult but I am not sure how to insert a word within that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick hint for you. Split the string and check if the word starts with `#`, if yes, append the words at the beginning and end.
use `startsWith` in java

```
1) Split the words using 'split function'

2) If(word.startsWith("#")) { 
    word = "ANSI_YELLOW "+word +   " ANSI_RESET";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working using this. I got a bit confused with the first part but it worked with `text.split(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

For stuff like that, regular expressions are your friend:

```
String text = "Hello world #computerScience";
text = text.replaceAll("(#\\w+)", "ANSI_YELLOW$1ANSI_RESET");
// Hello world ANSI_YELLOW#computerScienceANSI_RESET

String text = "Hello world #java #color #hashtag";
text = text.replaceAll("(#\\w+)", "ANSI_YELLOW$1ANSI_RESET");
// Hello world ANSI_YELLOW#javaANSI_RESET ANSI_YELLOW#colorANSI_RESET ANSI_YELLOW#hashtagANSI_RESET
```

Comment: I believe you are right but I am getting an error `Illegal group reference` which I believe might be a syntax error

Comment: @Sacert What replacement value are you giving? `$1` refers to capture group `1` of the search regex, so if you have `$2` or any other number, you'd get that error.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is written as follows

```
text = text.replaceAll("(#\\w+)", ANSI_YELLOW + " $1 " + ANSI_RESET);
```

and either ANSI_YELLOW or ANSI_REST contains "$" character, would get "Illegal group reference".